# How to change mass of object to fall slower with gravity in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a game with leaves in sprite kit. I have enabled gravity and such and created a ground in the game. When the game starts, gravity is simulated and the leaf falls onto the ground and stops. That’s great, but the current speed of the leaf is too fast and doesn’t seem realistic and once I get further into development I want larger leaves to “weigh” more and fall faster (meaning I don’t just want to change the world’s gravity). I thought if i just changed the leaf’s mass it would change the speed, but no. Changing it to any number, such as a small one like.0000002 did nothing to change the speed. Any idea what’s going on?

Comment: http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/gen99/gen99110.htm

Comment: So what properties do I change?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/density

Comment: I’m changing mass and density and nothing’s happening!

Comment: From reading the documentation.  You may want to try changing linear damping..  "This property is used to simulate fluid or air friction forces on the body. The property must be a value between 0.0 and 1.0. The default value is 0.1. If the value is 0.0, no linear damping is applied to the object."

Comment: Physics 101: an object's mass does not affect how much it accelerates due to gravity. In a perfect vacuum (ie ignoring air resistance) a feather will fall at the same speed as a cannon ball. In 2D physics engines the air resistance is not part of the simulation.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to didMoveToView():

```
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -0.5)
```

That will make the leaves more 'floaty' along the Y axis.

Comment: Thank you. Earth's gravity is not universal :-D ! I am working on a moon game for example.

Comment: **Swift 5.3**  physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -0.5)